# How to yield multiple promises in for loop with vo.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, promise, flow-control

Based on this example - [vo/examples/9-pipeline-composition.js](https://github.com/matthewmueller/vo/blob/master/examples/9-pipeline-composition.js), how would I `return yield` a promise for each iteration of this for loop?

At the moment the loop runs once and yields a single promise.

```
 function * get (urls) {
    for (var i = urls.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(urls[i])
        return yield http.get(urls[i]) 
    }
}

function status (res, params) {
    return res.status
}

let scrape = vo(get(['http://standupjack.com', 'https://google.com']), status)

vo([ scrape ])
.then(out => console.log('out', out))
.catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When u do the return inside the for loop, the loop breaks and returns the result and the loop wont move forward. You can call a function inside the for loop which handles the result and not return it.

```
function * get (urls) {
  for (var i = urls.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(urls[i])
    let result = yield http.get(urls[i])
    yield handleResult(result)
  }
}
```

Orelse u can push each of the results in an array and return all of then together at the end

```
function * get (urls) {
  let resArr = []
  for (var i = urls.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(urls[i])
    let result = yield http.get(urls[i])
    resArr.push(result)
  }
  return resArr
}
```